# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Pais y Ciudad.php on line 17 nose por que lo marca

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head><title>Pais y ciudad</title></head>
<body>
<table width="50%" border="10">
<?php
$ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Estados Unidos","Lugar"=>"Miami");
$ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Estados Unidos","Lugar"=>"Nueva Orleans");
$ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Inglaterra","Lugar"=>"Londres");
$ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Irlanda Del Norte","Lugar"=>"Belfast");
$ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Mexico","Lugar"=>"Tejupilco");
$ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Alemania","Lugar"=>"Berlin");

foreach($ciudad as $Key => $Row){
Echo "$Row[Pais]".""."$Row[Lugar]."."<BR>".";}

$NumElementos=Count($ciudad);
Echo "<TR><TD><P>Ciudad</P></TD> <TD><P>Pais</P></TD></TR>";

For($i=0;$i<$NumElementos;$i++){
Echo "<TR><TD><center>".$ciudad[$i]["Lugar"]."</center></TD></TR> "; 
}
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tu código tiene cierto desorden y líneas de mas te recomiendo que investigues sobre arrays asociativos multidimensionales en PHP y empezarías a ordenarlo mas

Answer (score 3):

**Te recomiendo refactorizar tu código** por que mas allá de que es muy dificil de leer; puedes lograr lo mismo con una mejor estructura y menos líneas de código

**OBSERVACIONES A TU CÓDIGO**

1. Lo primero es que si vas a tener mútiples arreglos asociativos, por ejemplo hagas uno solo pero que sea multidimensional; es decir que guarde varios arrays dentro de el
2. Lo segundo es que con dos foreach leas el recorrido y finalmente imprimas en una tabla
3. Lo ultimo que haces de count no me queda claro que quieres lograr asi que si me lo dices con gusto lo añado a la respuesta, pero todo esto que te recomiendo te va a ayudar a mejorar tu código

---

**Muestra del código funcional**

```
<html>
<head><title>Pais y ciudad</title></head>
<style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>estado</th>
        <th>Ciudad</th>
    </tr>
<?php

$destinos = array(
    array("estado" => "michoacan", "ciudad" => "zitacuaro"),
    array("estado" => "mexico", "ciudad" => "toluca"),
    array("estado" => "df", "ciudad" => "magdalena contreras")
);

foreach($destinos as $destino => $estado){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($estado as $e => $ciudad){
        echo "<td>".$ciudad."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Resultado obtenido**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por otro lado te hago las siguientes observaciones**

> 1. Respeta la escritura de las palabras reservadas, pues aunque PHP es permisivo eso hace dificil mantener tu código
>
> `echo` va en minúsculas `for` va en minúsculas
>
> Lo mismo que todas las demás etiquetas HTML que pusiste en mayúsculas
>    - Elemento de lista

Answer (score 0):

hay unas comillas de más la final de esta línea:

```
Echo "$Row[Pais]".""."$Row[Lugar]."."<BR>".";}

$NumElementos=Count($ciudad);
```

Que provoca que el string cierre justo después de `Echo` en esta línea:

```
Echo "<TR><TD><P>Ciudad</P></TD> <TD><P>Pais</P></TD></TR>";
```

el `<` del `<TR>` se interpreta como "menor que" y el `>` es el unexpected del error.

**nota** para evitar este tipo de errores sirve mucho usar un editor que coloree la sintaxis del lenguaje. Fijate como el primer `Echo` se ve celeste (indica una palabra clave/funcion/instrucción) y el segundo se ve marrón/rojo oscuro (indica string)

```
foreach($ciudad as $Key => $Row){
Echo "$Row[Pais]".""."$Row[Lugar]."."<BR>".";}

$NumElementos=Count($ciudad);
Echo "<TR><TD><P>Ciudad</P></TD> <TD><P>Pais</P></TD></TR>";
```

---

y corregido, nótese como cambian los colores:

```
foreach($ciudad as $Key => $Row){
Echo "$Row[Pais]".""."$Row[Lugar]."."<BR>";}

$NumElementos=Count($ciudad);
Echo "<TR><TD><P>Ciudad</P></TD> <TD><P>Pais</P></TD></TR>";
```

Answer (score -1):

TU CÓDIGO CORREGIDO

```
<html>
    <head><title>Pais y ciudad</title></head>
    <body>
    <table width="50%" border="10">
    <?php
    $ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Estados Unidos","Lugar"=>"Miami");
    $ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Estados Unidos","Lugar"=>"Nueva Orleans");
    $ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Inglaterra","Lugar"=>"Londres");
    $ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Irlanda Del Norte","Lugar"=>"Belfast");
    $ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Mexico","Lugar"=>"Tejupilco");
    $ciudad=Array("Pais"=>"Alemania","Lugar"=>"Berlin");

    foreach($ciudad as $Key => $Row){
      echo $Row["Pais"]." ".$Row["Lugar"]." <BR> ";
    }

        $NumElementos=Count($ciudad);
        echo "<TR><TD><P>Ciudad</P></TD> <TD><P>Pais</P></TD></TR>";

        for($i=0;$i<$NumElementos;$i++){
          echo "<TR><TD><center>".$ciudad[$i]["Lugar"]."</center></TD></TR> "; 
        }
    ?>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: no, yo acabo de probar tu script y sigue teniendo errores asi que no esta corregido

Comment: te sugiero que antes de postear una respuesta verifiques que funcione